# How to search for a previous, next id with SQLITE

Tags: java, sqlite

In the code as follows in android studio java, I want to search for the previous and next _id from a SQLite database.

```java
getData(id);

//get data
private void getData(long id) {
    @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = mDb.query(DataContract.DataListEntry.TABLE_NAME,
            null,
            DataContract.DataListEntry._ID + "=?",
            new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
            null,
            null,
            null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    String link = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataContract.DataListEntry.COLUMN_LINK));

}
```